# How to find whether software is installed or not in windows/mac using javascript or nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, macos, node-modules

My requirement is using Javascript I need to check whether xyz.msi/xyz.pkg application is installed or not in windows & mac system.

But I could not find any solution so I am trying through NodeJS. I have the following doubts

1. Will NodeJS help me to achieve above requirement?
2. Is there any way to get list of installed application using nodeJS
3. or by passing particular application name can I get information about that application using NodeJS.

If anyone has ideas, Please kindly share it.

Comment: How would you install msi application on Mac?
Anyway, the only option i can see is to find files via fs package and try to analyze what is 'Installed application'

Comment: @g.e.manor .. sorry I didn't mention mac file extension in question. For mac .pkg is the file extension.

Comment: simply you can try npm ls --json command to know all the installed modules

Comment: @ShekharTyagi npm ls is for node modules installed for local and global but OP is asking for any .pkg or .msi installed

Comment: @Shekhar .. I don't want installed node modules. I need a list of applications which are installed in the system.

Comment: @Mahesh the way that apps installed on OS X and Win is bit different
What you can do in OS X is search for files in the ~/Applications folder and find contextual way to normalize those search into an good array for your results
I'm not sure what is the right way to do it in Win but there is no native Node.JS API to fetch that list

Comment: For windows there is an VB code https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/8035d5a9-dc92-436d-a60c-67d381da15a3 If you can find a way to re-write this in node by getting the file it can help you

Comment: @g.e.manor .. Thanks for the reply. I am using windows, I am not able to find out .msi file installation path after installation. I have checked 'C:\program files' folder but it's not there. I could see it in control panel --> add or remove list.

Comment: @VinodLouis .. Thank you so much. I will try that way.

Comment: @Mahesh Win, not like OS X isn't using the MSI file after the install. MSI is installing package, is like that you'll don't find the .pkg file after install and you'll find the .dmg file

Comment: Regards @VinodLouis answer, i think it's not should be so hard to run the VBscript via Node.JS but may i'm wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tips：

I'm not sure javascript but node.js.

when you exec your project in node.js, you've has operate permission to do anything on your platform of os.

you can use child_process of node.js to exec shell on your pro and watch stdout to check if you have installed.

Comment: any clue on this?